# Find scale between three colors

Tags: android, colors

I am not a Android developer, but my team members required the same thing I did on the web. I required a function to which I pass any three colors (e.g. red,blue,green), and I will pass a count, e.g. 100.

Definition of function

```
function getColorArray(mincolor,midcolor,maxcolor,100){
    return colorarray;
}
```

When I have to call function:

```
getColorArray(red,yellow,green,100)
```

So it will give a array of 100 colors from a red,blue,green color scale.

I did it in Javascript. Here is the [fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/dssoft32/2otLtbuo/).

I want the same output in Android.

Comment: Had originally (and erroneously) posted this as an answer;

I'm already having a hard time figuring out what it's supposed to do. Simply return iterated colors where the first color is the first step, the second color is the middle (in your example 50th step) and the third is the last step? Why not use actual gradients?

Also; the output should generally be an array of hex-colors, as in the fiddle?

Comment: Yes, the output should be array. i wrote this in java script. need help to convert it into java. any library that help ?

Comment: Worth checking this out. It could simplify a lot of the work for you, using the JavaFX Color class and its interpolate method. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/paint/Color.html#interpolate-javafx.scene.paint.Color-double-

Answer (score 1):

This code does a simple line interpolation (c1 - c2, c2 - c3) . Your example JS code has richer options than this simple example (non linear interpolations), but I think this should help you get started.

You should probably define some custom colors if you're going to let the users name the colors - the default range of system colors is pretty limited (at least with `java.awt.Color` predifined colors, that is).

```java
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class ColorTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = args.length > 0 ? Integer.parseInt(args[0]) : 5;
        Color[] test = getColorArray("red", "green", "blue", n);
        for(Color c : test) {
            System.out.println(c);
        }
    }
    
    public static Color[] getColorArray(String c1, String c2, String c3, int n) {
        Color[] inputColors = new Color[3];
        try {
            Field field1 = Color.class.getField(c1);
            Field field2 = Color.class.getField(c2);
            Field field3 = Color.class.getField(c3);
        
            inputColors[0] = (Color) field1.get(null); 
            inputColors[1] = (Color) field2.get(null);
            inputColors[2] = (Color) field3.get(null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("One of the color values is not defined!");
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    
        Color[] result = new Color[n];
    
        int[] c1RGB = { inputColors[0].getRed(), inputColors[0].getGreen(), inputColors[0].getBlue() };
        int[] c2RGB = { inputColors[1].getRed(), inputColors[1].getGreen(), inputColors[1].getBlue() };
        int[] c3RGB = { inputColors[2].getRed(), inputColors[2].getGreen(), inputColors[2].getBlue() };
        int[] tmpRGB = new int[3];
    
        tmpRGB[0] = c2RGB[0] - c1RGB[0];
        tmpRGB[1] = c2RGB[1] - c1RGB[1];
        tmpRGB[2] = c2RGB[2] - c1RGB[2];
        float mod = n/2.0f; 
        for (int i = 0; i < n/2; i++) {
            result[i] = new Color(
                (int) (c1RGB[0] + i/mod*tmpRGB[0]) % 256, 
                (int) (c1RGB[1] + i/mod*tmpRGB[1]) % 256,
                (int) (c1RGB[2] + i/mod*tmpRGB[2]) % 256
            );
        }
    
        tmpRGB[0] = c3RGB[0] - c2RGB[0];
        tmpRGB[1] = c3RGB[1] - c2RGB[1];
        tmpRGB[2] = c3RGB[2] - c2RGB[2];
        for (int i = 0; i < n/2 + n%2; i++) {
            result[i+n/2] = new Color(
                (int) (c2RGB[0] + i/mod*tmpRGB[0]) % 256, 
                (int) (c2RGB[1] + i/mod*tmpRGB[1]) % 256,
                (int) (c2RGB[2] + i/mod*tmpRGB[2]) % 256
            );
        }
    
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: this logic suits best in java. but i have to implenment it in Android. there is no AWt package. any suggestion ?

Comment: Should work with https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html - The difference being that you use Color's static methods to get your Colors (parseColor(), rgb()).

Comment: I took another look at it - it seems that you cannot work with Color objects directly but rather with `int`s that represent them (there's no `new Color(...)`). So you have to re-write my `getColorArray()` so that it will return an array of integers.